# find the normalizer of $A?$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G= S_3$ and let $A$ be the subgroup $\{1,(1,2)\}$

find  $N_{S_3}(A)?$ where $N_{S_3}(A)$ denote the normalizer

**My attempt** :let $\sigma \in S_3$. Define  a  map $f :A \to A$ by  $f(a)=\sigma a \sigma^{-1}$

Then $f(a)\subseteq A$

$\implies$ every element of $S_3$ is in  $N_{S_3}(A)$

Therefore $N_{S_3}(A)= S_3$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The image of $f$ is $A$ if, and only if, $\sigma \in N_{S_3}(A)$: your argument is circular and the conclusion is wrong. Let $\sigma = (1 \; 2 \;3)$. Then:
  $$\sigma \circ (1\;2)\circ\sigma^{-1} = (2 \; 3) \notin A$$
  so $\sigma \notin N_{S_3}(A)$.
- A correct proof is as follows: take $\sigma \in S_3$. Then $\sigma \in N_{S_3}(A)$ if, and only if, $\sigma \circ (1\;2)\circ  \sigma^{-1} = (1\;2)$. Since $\sigma \circ (1\;2)\circ  \sigma^{-1} = (\sigma(1) \; \sigma(2))$, we see that the only solutions are the identity and $(1\;2)$. Therefore:
  $$N_{S_3}(A) = A$$

Answer (score 3):

Put $G=S_3$. You can almost do this hands down, you need to remark that $A \subseteq N_G(A) \subseteq G$, so $|G:N_G(A)|=1 $ or $=3$. But $N_G(A)=G$ if and only if $A \unlhd G$. So you only need to check that $A$ is *not* normal. And this will lead to $N_G(A)=A$ in this case. So your argument in false unfortunately.